# Articles for the words "camp" & "pub"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

1) I've just read this article http://masteringarticles.com/object-activity-nouns/ and it says that "pub" is not a common activity noun, so when we say **I want to go to the pub** the word should be instead pluralized, rather than getting a *the*. However, I heard phrases like **Right, let's go to the pub** with no precursory reference to the pub. So, what's the right way to say?
2) I heard the phrase "in camp", though it's neither a common activity noun, nor something else. Why do we omit the article here?

Comment: That's one of the worst articles on the definite article I've ever read.

Comment: When people say 'Right  let's go to the pub' they have a specific pub in mind. Their local, as many British people put it rather than any random pub, it follows the rule for a specific church mentioned in part one of the article.

Comment: I agree with Clare; that article is really confusing.  Also, I think you misread it, because it's saying (I think) not to use the article with common activity nouns, but **pub** is a place, not a common activity.